# Text-Block on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gtk, text, url

I have a problem with the textbox on Ubuntu 12.04. Every time I want to edit existing text, either in LibreOffice or even a URL Bar, always appears an annoying text-block (or something?). Can this problem be solved? Is this due to the GTK theme?

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Has your keyboard toggled the "insert" key for overtype?

Comment: @Hydrangea : Thanks! The problem is solved now! :D

Comment: @Hydrangea could you add that as an answer so that it can be accepted please :)

Comment: Just did. I felt like it was a question moreso than an answer, originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the keyboard has the Insert key toggled and is in overtype mode.